# how to fix bad gateway issue in android studio

Tags: android, kotlin, mapbox

currently I've come across this issue in this android studio project that was done by someone else. Howeveer I am not entirely sure how to fix this issue, let alone figure out what is causing it.

I am relatively new to android studio, hence why I need a little help here

This is the error "Could not HEAD 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox/com/mapbox/mapboxsdk/mapbox-android-sdk/9.5.0/mapbox-android-sdk-9.5.0.pom'. Received status code 502 from server: Bad Gateway"

This is in the build.gradle file which is the closest I could find to that link above

```
repositories {
        google()
        mavenCentral()
        maven { url 'https://mapbox.bintray.com/mapbox' }

    }
```

Any help is greatly appreciated please, thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mapbox is not available on bintray anymore. Check out the new implementation guide to see how to add the mapbox sdk as a dependency to gradle: https://docs.mapbox.com/android/maps/guides/install/#add-the-dependency

The new repository URL for mapbox is `https://api.mapbox.com/downloads/v2/releases/maven`.

Comment: nice thank you!!